# stop creating certain cases email to case

Tags: email2case

we use email-to-case but a lot of unwanted cases are been created, we want to know what is the best way to stop cases getting created when we receive emails from certain email addresses.

we don't use 'Accept email from' feature in email-to case settings.

we don't have access to outlook exchange server to create any filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of the scenario can be handled using validation rule.

When email-to-case occurs, you can capture `Web Email Address` and based on this create a validation rule to throw some dummy error message.

This error message is consumed internally and it doesn't go to Admin or that user's emailId as an email.

*I have used this approach in my project and it served my purpose.*

Comment: Thanks Santanu, but I was hoping to know if there is a way to prevent cases being created when an email comes from certain email addresses. I know i can create assignment rule to send cases to a different queue when web email matches to certain email address.

Comment: If you use above approach then case will not get created

Comment: Hi santanu, thank you for pointing me out . only thing which is not seems to be working is that , when no case is created then system is sending an email notification to 'automated case user' with the following message (FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION : can not create case from this email address).    Is there a way to stop this or I might have to change Automated user to myself and create some sort of rule in outlook to redirect those emails to a folder .

Comment: You can change automated case user as a Dummy user with an invalid email id so that no email will get sent to that user

Comment: of course if you do this (automated case user = dummy user w/ invalid email), legitimate E2C email issues will fail silently

Answer (score 1):

We created a custom meta-data type to store blocked domains and would add domains to the list when we started to receive spam. Then in your custom email handler you'd check the email against this list and if any entries are returned you simply don't create the case.